# Error using Javascript filter() function in freecodecamp

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

```
function destroyer(arr) {

var arry=[];


for(var i=1;i<arr.length;i++)
{
  arr[0] = arr[0].filter(cc => cc != arr[i]);
}
return arry;
}

destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3);
```

I basically have to return all the elements of the first sub-array which arent present in the rest of array.

> Its displaying "arr[0].filter isnt a function.
>   destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3) should return [1, 1].
>   I basically have to return all the elements of the first sub-array which arent present in the array.

Comment: Your `destroyer` function is only expecting one argument `arr`. 

Additionally, the filter method operates on an array. Currently, you're trying to run filter on the first value of `arr` .

I would give the [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) documentation one more read through first and see if that will help you solve your question!

Answer (score 0):

You aren't doing anything with the other arguments provided to the `destroyer` function - you have to test *those* arguments against `arr`, you shouldn't be testing `arr` against itself.

```js
function destroyer() {
  const [arr, ...excludeArr] = arguments;
  return arr.filter(elm => !excludeArr.includes(elm));
}

console.log(
  destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function destroyer(arr, x, y) {
return arr.filter(item => (item != x) && (item != y))
}

console.log(destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3))
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const destroyer = (arr, ...args) => {
  return arr.filter(item => args.indexOf(item) < 0);
};

const result = destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to call your method using the array. you have to surround it with another pair of `[]`.

You can simply return the filtered `arr[0]` to get what you want.

```js
function destroyer(arr) {
  for (var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr[0] = arr[0].filter(cc => cc != arr[i]);
  }
  return arr[0];
}

 
console.log(destroyer([[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3]));
```

Comment: I am damn sure, with out declaring variable arr ,also we can achieve it.

Comment: I just wanted to keep the function call clean.

Answer (score 0):

as you said you should filter first subarray but you are sending only 1 array with int values and other values as argument, the actual usage of this function should be

```js
function destroyer(arr) {

  for(var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++)
  {
    arr[0] = arr[0].filter(cc => cc != arr[i]);
  }

  return arr[0];
}

destroyer([[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3]);
```